# Discord.js: Fetch Message by ID gives wrong output

Tags: node.js, promise, bots, discord, discord.js

When I got help from another user I tried it out for a fetchMessage() by the id. Something went wrong I suppose because when I put in the ID for my report command it return as `[object Promise]` instead of the message that the ID corresponds with. Here is a code bit and what it outputs:

```
if (cmd === `${prefix}report`) {
    let messageID = args[0];
    if (isNaN(messageID)) {
        message.author.send("Not an ID")
        return;
    }
    let messagea = message.channel.fetchMessages(messageID);
    let reportEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Reports")
        .setColor("#F7E533")
        .addField("Message", messagea)
        .addField("Reported User", `@${messagea.author}`)
        .addField("Reported By", `${message.author} with ID: ${message.author.id}`)
        .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
    let reportschannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, botconfig.reportsChannel);
    if (!reportschannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find reports channel.");

    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    reportschannel.send(reportEmbed);
    message.delete();
    return;
}
```

[image: The Output]

Comment: If it returns a promise you need to wait until you get the result from that promise, and then send the message,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message.channel.fetchMessages(messageID)` returns a **Promise** not a message, and also you should use [`fetchMessage`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessage) instead of `fetchMessages`.
You need to wait for that promise "to give you information" and then do what you need.

```
message.channel.fetchMessage(messageID).then(messagea => {
    let reportEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Reports")
        .setColor("#F7E533")
        .addField("Message", messagea.content)
        .addField("Reported User", `@${messagea.author}`)
        .addField("Reported By", `${message.author} with ID: ${message.author.id}`)
        .addField("Time", message.createdAt)
    let reportschannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, botconfig.reportsChannel);
    if (!reportschannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find reports channel.");

    message.delete().catch(O_o => {});
    reportschannel.send(reportEmbed);
    message.delete();
    return;
})
```

And also I've changed `messagea` to `messagea.content` so it actually displays the message

Comment: Yes this works. Thank You!
PS: I did change the `fetchMessages` to `fetchMessage` but I didn't know how to get the content. Thank You again!